# Is the sequence $x_n = \frac{\sin 1}{2} + \frac{\sin 2}{2^2} + \frac{\sin 3}{2^3} +\dots + \frac{\sin n}{2^n}$ Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

$$x_{n} = \frac{\sin 1}{2} + \frac{\sin 2}{2^2} + \frac{\sin 3}{2^3} + ... + \frac{\sin n}{2^n}$$

I came across this sequence while studying, and while it is convergent, I'm curious as to whether or not it is a Cauchy sequence. If so, what's the proof?

Comment: hint: $|\sin n|<1$.

Comment: Convergent sequences are Cauchy. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Sequence_is_Cauchy_Sequence

Comment: Is using cauchy sequence the most straightforward way in proving that this sequence is convergent?

Comment: This is closely related: [Proving convergence of $\sum \frac{\sin n}{2^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/945224)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n > m > 0$, we have

$\vert x_n - x_m \vert = \vert \sum_{m + 1}^n \dfrac{\sin i}{2^i} \vert \le \sum_{m + 1}^n \dfrac{\vert \sin i \vert}{2^i} \le \sum_{m + 1}^n \dfrac{1}{2^i}, \tag{1}$

since $\vert \sin i \vert \le 1$.  But

$\sum_{m + 1}^n \dfrac{1}{2^i} = \dfrac{1}{2^{m + 1}} \sum_0^{n - m -1}\dfrac{1}{2^i} \le 2\dfrac{1}{2^{m + 1}} = \dfrac{1}{2^m}, \tag{2}$

since $\sum_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^i} = 2$. Thus by taking $m$ sufficiently large, we may make $\vert x_n - x_m \vert$ arbitrarily small; the sequence is Cauchy.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I get the math here, but how large should m be exactly?

Comment: You pick $\epsilon$ as small as you want, then pick $m$ so that $2^{-m} \le \epsilon$; then $\vert x_n - x_m \vert \le \epsilon$; for any $\epsilon$, there is such an $m$; that's what makes the sequence Cauchy.

Comment: Or, since it's Rosh Hashanah, maybe I should say the sequence is ***Kosher***!  And ***L'Shanah Tovah!!!*** to one and all!

Comment: This follows from sin being the imaginary part of exp and then summing a geometric series and taking the imaginary part.

Comment: @martycohen:  you mean as in $\sum_k \frac{e^{i k}}{2^k}$, a complex geometric series of ratio $e^i/2$?  That's pretty cool!  By the way, Happy New Year!

Comment: @martycohen:  worthy of being posted as an answer, in my book.  I'd upvote it!  Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

You could be interested to notice that quite simple manipulations of the sines of multiple angles lead to  $$x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin (i)}{2^i}= \frac{2^{-n} \left(\sin (n)-2 \sin (n+1)+2^{n+1} \sin (1)\right)}{5-4 \cos (1)}$$ Similarly $$x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin (i)}{3^i}=\frac{3^{-n} \left(\sin (n)-3 \sin (n+1)+3^{n+1} \sin (1)\right)}{10 - 6 \cos (1)}$$ $$x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin (i)}{4^i}=\frac{4^{-n} \left(\sin (n)-4 \sin (n+1)+4^{n+1} \sin (1)\right)}{17-8 \cos (1)}$$

If fact, for **any** value of $k$

$$x_n(k)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin (i)}{k^i}=\frac{k^{-n} \left(\sin (n)-k \sin (n+1)+k^{n+1} \sin (1)\right)}{1+k^2-2 k \cos (1)}$$

Comment: Now *that* is Truly Amazing! +1!

Comment: This beats me! You summed up the series directly. +1

Comment: @RobertLewis. I totally agree : it becomes an amazing problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: I must hand it to you once again:  I *never* would have thought of that!  My answer, as you will note, sticks to the prosaic and exceedingly well-known methods.  And Cheers to you , sir! ;-)

Comment: I thank you again, young man ! Have a look to what I added to my answer.

Comment: I saw it!  You, my good sir, stand on a peak shared only by Srinivasa Ramanujan!

Comment: Stop kidding me ! I am just an amateur in these areas. Obviously, you and I share the same mistress : Mathematics. I must say that my field is modestly applied mathematics ut I have fun with this kind of problems. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\displaystyle|x_n-x_m|=|\sum^{n}_{k=m+1} \frac{\sin k}{2^k}|\le |\sum^{n}_{k=m} \frac{1}{2^k}|$, but the last term can be made less than $\epsilon$ since it is seqeunce of partial sums of convergent series $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{1}{2^k}$